# Can't access Docker container web address (172.17.0.2) from windows

Tags: docker, prometheus, docker-machine, docker-container, docker-desktop

i'm using docker desktop , I have runned prometheus as a container :

[image]

the commande docker inspect  is showing that this container is running on the gateway 172.17.0.2 on port 9090 .

"Networks": {
"bridge": {
"IPAMConfig": null,
"Links": null,
"Aliases": null,
"NetworkID": "a112bcf4dbabbfdb5b3e14c9d286469a482557c78d42854a5ae3e754ca44fd5d",
"EndpointID": "0ecc79513b555daebb51947a6a6a73bb26f0974542a6f79d14013b8b1572a589",
"Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
"IPPrefixLen": 16,
"IPv6Gateway": "",
"GlobalIPv6Address": "",
"GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
"MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
"DriverOpts": null
}
}

but when this address is not rechable in my browser .

could any one please help

Comment: Could you please provide the docker run command used to start that container?. And another couple of questions. Have you [exposed 9090 port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)? Have you tried using `localhost:9090`?

Comment: hello, localhost 9090 is also not reachable , and to start the container i have used just the button run in docker desktop .

Comment: Accessing the bridge network from the host is implementation dependent. It works on Linux but not on Windows. So don't do it. Map the ports you need and access the container that way.

Comment: Hello Hans, i'm a new learner of docker , what do you mean by mapping the ports you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct: you can't access the `docker inspect` IP address on a Windows host.  You also can't access it from a MacOS host, if your Docker is more explicitly inside a virtual machine (using Docker Toolbox or a tool like Minikube for your Docker environment), or if you're calling from a different host from the container.  This IP address is almost never useful and you shouldn't need to look it up at all.

When you start a container, you have the option to [publish ports](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) from it.  If Prometheus normally listens on port 9000, this could look like

```sh
docker run \
  -d \                # in the background
  --name prometheus \ # with a name so it's easier to manage
  -p 9123:9000 \      # host port 9123 -> container port 9000
  bitnami/prometheus
```

The second port number must exactly match what the image is expecting.  The first port number can be anything that's not otherwise in use.  The ports are frequently the same but don't have to be.

Once you have this `docker run -p` option, you can use the first port number to access the container; `http://localhost:9123` if you're on the same host (and aren't using Docker Toolbox or a similar VM-based setup).

If you don't have this option, `docker stop` and `docker rm` the existing container and `docker run` a new one with the right settings.  This is extremely routine, very similar to using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop a command-line process and then run it with different command-line arguments.

Comment: Hello , thank you a lot form this explanation , i have use the commande mentionned : C:\Users\21620>docker run -d --name prometheus -p 9123:9000 bitnami/prometheus
b8b92fc3f08662b684ea4530e878c81107f605ff4081b730f51f7bae94a24ac0

but still could not access with localhost:9123

Comment: this what look the commande docker ps :     C:\Users\21620>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                              NAMES
b8b92fc3f086   bitnami/prometheus   "/opt/bitnami/promet…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   9090/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9123->9000/tcp   prometheus                                                    it show that the container is well running .

Comment: Hello , this work well for me now , the problem is that prometheus port is on 9090 and not 9000 , thank you all :D